# Using the Kendo Grid, Can you Find if a column is hidden upon the DataBound Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo Grid. I have the ColumnMenu enabled so that the user can hide and show columns. I want to hide or disable my bulk action buttons my checkbox column is hidden. What's the best way to to determine if a column is hidden in the DataBound event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dataBound event, you can access the grid with

```
var grid = e.sender;
```

And the grid will have a columns collection.

```
grid.columns
```

If you dump that to the console, the columns that are not visible have a hidden property set to false.  This is a dump of a 3 column grid's column property in the dataBound event.

```
[[object Object] {
  encoded: true,
  field: "name"
}, [object Object] {
  attributes: [object Object] {
    style: "display:none"
  },
  encoded: true,
  field: "age",
  footerAttributes: [object Object] {
    style: "display:none"
  },
  headerAttributes: [object Object] {
    style: "display:none"
  },
  hidden: true
}, [object Object] {
  encoded: true,
  field: "city"
}]
```

Here you can see the field for "age" has a property hidden: true.
See sample http://jsbin.com/OxEToYA/1/edit